# Restore Recycler View state on device's rotation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rotation, screen-orientation, onscrolllistener

I have RecyclerView which views are populated from the internet (page number is a parameter) and that is why I used the [EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/d09dc68ff07e845cc622). The only problem is that when I rotate the device, it doesn't restore the same state.

This is my ScrollListener initiation in **onCreate()**:

```
        mScrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(mGridLayoutManager) {

            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                mPage++;
                new TheMovieRequestTask().execute();
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(mScrollListener);
```

**onSaveInstanceState():**

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("mPageKey", mPage);

    mListState = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable("mListStateKey", mListState);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

At the beginning of **onCreate()** I have:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("mPageKey");

        mBundleRecyclerViewState = new Bundle();
        mListState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("mListStateKey");
        mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable("mListStateBundleKey", mListState);

    } else {
        mPage = 1;
    }
```

And when I load data from TheMovieRequestTask() (it's an AsyncTask), in **onPostExecute()** i have:

```
if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
    Parcelable state = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable("mListStateBundleKey");                  
    mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

What Can I do? When I go back from another activity, it's perfect but on rotation, it just doesn't work.

This code loads e.g. 5th page and then properly restore it but then I can scroll only down (6,7,8,9... pages) but **not up**(not 4,3,2,1, pages).

Comment: Did you override the `onConfigurationChanges` method?

Comment: No, I didn't. Of course, I can always edit manifest file and type "           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" but it doesn't seem to be a proper solution.

Comment: Yes I think you should and this is where you restore the `RecyclerView` state from `savedInstanceState`.